# jquery loading content unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.blue-anim').hover(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.blue-anim').load('/web #physics')
    }, 1000);
    $('.bluefigcaption').text("Physics").removeClass('blue_figcaption').addClass('new_caption');

    }, function(){
        $('.blue-anim').load('/web #past');
        $('.blue figcaption').text("Past").removeClass('new_caption').addClass('blue_figcaption');
    }
);
```

This is my java script for hover an image. The hover in works correctly as it replaces as image with another image with load(). The hoverout also works which essentially brings back the old image. But just after the hoverout jquery again bring the hoverin image back. When I check in firebug, I see that the load() function in hoverin in again being run. Just the load() function nothing else. Why is it happening? Is the load script embedded in the html or something? If so how can I remove it?

Comment: Does the problem persist when you remove the `setTimeout` function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reassemble your code, this

```js
$(function () {
    $(".blue-anim").hover(function() {
        $(".blue-anim").load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxmatko/xDev.RequireJs/master/README.md");
        $('.blue-figcaption')
            .text("Physics")
            .removeClass('blue-figcaption')
            .addClass('new-caption');
    }, function() {
        $(this).load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxmatko/xDev.Boilerplates/master/README.md");
        $('.new-caption')
            .text("Past")
            .removeClass('new-caption')
            .addClass('blue-figcaption');        
    });
});
```

```css
.blue-anim {
    background: blue;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}

.blue-figcaption {
    color: blue;
}

.new-caption {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue-anim">
</div>
<div class="blue-figcaption">
</div>
```

works for me